# Cannot find name 'request'. Did you mean 'Request'? ts(2552)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following js code:

```
let sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
try {
  let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
} catch (err) {
  return response.status(400).end();
}
```

**I need this code to be converted to typescript. Which I think would solve the error I am getting:**

> Cannot find name 'request'. Did you mean 'Request'?ts(2552)

Comment: How was `request` defined?

Comment: @Evert im following this https://medium.com/@GaryHarrower/working-with-stripe-webhooks-firebase-cloud-functions-5366c206c6c and it seems nowhere was it defined.

Comment: If you just want to create a new request object you need to defined it, e.g. `let request = new Request()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request.
If you are using the request library it needs to be imported first `const request = require('request')` https://github.com/request/request - but that library is no longer maintained so you might be better off with something like axios

Comment: @NCT127 he is using the above code snippet *inside* of a function which gets `request` from the arguments: `functions.https.onRequest((request, response)` https://github.com/GaryH21/Stripe-Webhooks-Tutorial/blob/master/functions/index.js

Comment: @LindaPaiste if you could add this as the answer I will accept. Thanks! (Include all the links)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request` is a variable and it must be defined.  You have copy and pasted a single piece of a tutorial, but this code snippet doesn't work in isolation.

The tutorial uses this code inside of a function which gets the `request` variable from its arguments.

```
exports.events = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  let sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
...
```

You can see this more clearly in their [completed code](https://github.com/GaryH21/Stripe-Webhooks-Tutorial/blob/master/functions/index.js).